# Access sales force object list without authentication

Tags: node.js, salesforce, soql

I have an salesforce object stores which needs to be accessed by all users(logged-in and guest users). I tried in "user profiles" but later realized its only for userd logged into the system that can have profile.

So what about guest users? how do guest users view data?

I am using [nodejs-nforce](https://github.com/kevinohara80/nforce) and didn't find anyting related to that.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, Salesforce don't provide API access without authorization, so you need always use SF credentials for querying Objects.

Answer (score 0):

Guest user profiles are not visible in the Setup>Profile section. Follow the below steps to go to the Guest user profile.

Navigate to Setup>Digital Experiences>All Sites>Builder
Guest User Profile section, click the profile name

Visit https://nonitechsolutions.blogspot.com/2021/06/salesforce-enable-guest-user-on-your.html